# What will happen to old data if data structure changes in hyperledger fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What will happen to old data if data structure changes in hyperledger fabric chaincode? will it affect when we read old data from couchdb and translate it into object of new structure? Lets say I've added a new field and removed old field in the structure. what will be the impact of this change to old data?

Answer (score 0):

**CouchDb is a Nosql DB**. You don't specify a schema to the records which would be created. The **records** are in the **form of a Document**. You can just relate a **record** in CouchDB as a **JSON**.

*Would JSON ever get affected by adding/deleting a key?*

*No, it doesn't*. It's just that the old records won't have that key which is being added to the new records. Therefore, you might not be able to retrieve old records only if you are filtering/querying the records with newly added key.

Hope this helps.